# Fetch Salesforce data that got updated after last pipeline run using ADF pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

The use case is to pull data from Salesforce to Azure SQL Server. The pipeline will run on a scheduled trigger and on every run, we need to fetch data that was modified after the last pipeline run.

Need help to understand, how can we pass the pipeline trigger-time between each run and use it in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Data Factory supports Incrementally load data base on last modification.**To achieve our goal create table in your database to store each pipeline end time for future use.** Incremental copy can be done in several steps as follows:

1. Get the timestamp from last run of pipeline which we stored earlier
   in source dataset through as last update.
2. Get the timestamp from current run of pipeline through lookup
   activity from `utcnow()` function as new update.
3. Copy data changes from source to destination with the query that has
   condition as from last update timestamp to current    timestamp
   which we got from previous steps.
4. Update the current timestamp value in table which store the
   timestamp for the pipeline run as last update timestamp for future
   use.

then trigger the pipeline as per your requirement to copy data which is updated after last pipeline run.

**Reference:** [Incrementally copy data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-overview)